# Magento 2: How to paste remarketing code in the <body> section

Tags: magento2

I need to add the tracking code from Google in the **`<body>`** section on each store page. Does anyone have any suggestions where to paste this code?

Comment: had you check below answer?

Comment: @ Chirag Rajput thanks for your help. yes I pasted here code and now check result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the codes in your Magento Admin under `Content --> Configuration --> Select your theme -->  Html Head Secion --> Script and Style Sheets`.